# Model a process of selecting boxes

Tags: probability, problem-solving, geometric-construction

I am considering the following process:

There are $m$ boxes in total and $n$ boxes are red and $0\leq n\leq m$. $m$ and $n$ are all very large. Now we have $K$ (very large) people, where $0\leq K\leq m$. Boxes are labeled from 1 to $m$.

In each round, everyone randomly submits a number form $1$ to $m$ that is completely independent of others. If the number a person submitted corresponds to a red box, then this person leave the system.

Because everyone's submission is completely random and is independent of others, hence, the number of submission each person makes is a geometric distribution with success probability $n/m$.

Now, consider this process as the base. We now put a treasure which has value $r$ in each red box. The whole process is the same as before. If it happens that a person submits a number which corresponds to a red box and that red box has a treasure, then the person will take that treasure (not the red box) with him. And hence, if later on this red box is called by other people, then there is no treasure in it. If in one round two people happen to call the same red box and this red box has never been called by people before, then the treasure is randomly assigned among the people who call it in this round.

My question is: what is the probability that when a person leaves the system, the red box he called has never been called by anyone else? Consider the situation when $n/m=p$ and $K/m=q$ and $m\rightarrow\infty$.

My attempt is the following:

Round  $~~~$ People Finish the Game  $~~~$ Red box with treasure left  $~~~$ Prob. get treasure

1 $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~A_1=qp$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~B_1=B_0-A_1B_0/p$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~1$

2 $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~A_2=A_1(1-p)$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~B_2=B_1-A_2B_1/p$  $~~~~~~~~~~~~~B_1/p$

$n$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~A_n=A_{n-1}(1-p)$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~B_n=B_{n-1}-A_nB_{n-1}/p$ $~~~~B_{n-1}/p$

where $B_0=p$. Then we consider all the cases: if a man finishes the game at round 1, 2, 3,..., n,... So the corresponding probability is 
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}pB_{i-1}/p\\
&=\frac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A_iB_{i-1}/p\\
&=\frac{1}{q}(B_0-B_1+B_1-B_2+B_2-B_3+....)\\
&=\frac{1}{q}B_0=p/q
\end{align*}

Is the last step correct? I think it may have some problem, as $B_i$ is bounded by $p$ for all $i$. Hence, the whole series should be bounded by 1 but now I get something that depends on $q$ and if $q$ is close to zero, then this $p/q$ can be greater than 1.

The above should be $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{i-1}e^{-[1-(1-p)^i]q/p}$

The idea is that if a man finishes the game in round 1, then he must call a red box in round 1 and clearly all red boxes in round 1 has never been called by all the other people. If a man finishes the game in round 2, then he must call a non-red box in round 1, which occurs with probability $(1-p)p$, then as during the round 1, there are already $qp$ red boxes being tapped by people in round 1, the left red boxes are $p-qp$. Hence, in round 2, a man, conditioning on he calls a red box, will have chance $\frac{p-qp}{p}$ to call a red box that has not been called by previous people.

Comment: I'm unclear about a couple of things.  If two people call the same number at the same time, do they both leave?  Do they divide the treasure?  (That is, does each get $r/2?$)  Also, do all the remaining people call their numbers at the same time?  Do they know which red boxes have already been selected, so that they know better than to call them again?

Comment: @saulspatz good questions. I think when $m$ goes to infinity, then the chance of 2 people call the same number will be zero, right? I also update the problem

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with the problem at all?  Should it be $n$ boxes are red?

Comment: @RossMillikan I just edit it. $n$ is the number of red boxes. I want to consider the situation when $n,m,K$ are all infinity but the ratio $n/m=p$ and $K/m=q$ are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the treasure in each box is given to one person by some random process if more than one calls the number the first time it is called or the treasure is divided, just use symmetry.  Everybody has an equal chance at a treasure, so the chance they get it is $\frac nK$.  The value to each person is then $\frac {nr}K$.  The details of how you select the winner don't matter as long as it is random.  The only way this fails is if you give a similar treasure to all the people who call the right number the first time it is called so the total value of treasures is higher than $r$ in some cases.

Comment: I kind of agree with you. I used a fairly complicated method, and I derive the same result as you, which is $r \frac{n/m}{K/m}=rp/q$. However, this still has a problem that I couldn't explain. If $p>q$ (i.e., more treasure than people), then this expression $rp/q$ means each people walks away with more than one treasure. How can that be, given the nature of the problem??? The people leave the game with at most one treasure. Where does the logic go wrong?

Comment: If there are more red boxes than people, everybody gets a red box and there are some red boxes left over.  If you want to consider that case you need to make the chance somebody gets a treasure $\max(1,rp/q)$

Comment: I am not sure if it is that simple, i.e., $\min\{1,p/q\}$ for this probability. I updated the post with my complicate method. I could't find where I go wrong

Comment: I think even if there are more red boxes than people, still a man can finish the game without getting a treasure. There is a positive probability such that a man finish the game in round 2 and chose a red box that has been tapped by some one in round 1.

Comment: I thought the box that was taken was removed.  If it stays in the game you are right.